# how to set timepicker value in Modal for edit the time?

Tags: php, timepicker

i'm still learning PHP, i have a table and have a update form to update the data.for update the data i'm using a Modal. so when i want to update the data in the table i just click the "update" button and then the popup menu for update the data will be show. for example in the update menu i have a name and time. for name, if i want to showed previous name in the text box i use this code: `value="<?php echo $row_menu['name']; ?>" required>` and the previous name will be displayed in the text box. so how about the time?how to displayed the previous time??
[image: image for my Modal Form]

and for the time i'm use this code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Time Start</label>
    <input type="Time" name="time">
</div>
```

i don't know how to set the "value" for timepicker to show the previous time. sorry for the bad english i hope you all understand what i mean

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value in input when page load or whenever the popup button open.

For this ,you have to write the below code:

```
var value = '<?php echo $valueforthis; ?>'
$('input[name="time"]').timepicker({defaultTime: value});
```

Please try this.